# On the locality of the gradient of a Sobolev function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $u,v\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and that $u = v$ on a Borel subset $E\subseteq \Omega$.

**Question:** is it true that $\nabla u= \nabla v$ a.e. in $E$?

Comment: You mean $\nabla u= \nabla v$ in $E$ or in $\Omega$?

Comment: I mean $E$, how could ever be true in $\Omega$.

Comment: I'm just curious how it can be, that $u=v$, but $\nabla u \neq \nabla v$ on the same set?

Comment: Well, indeed the result is known to be true. But I don't like the proof that I know. One first observes that it is sufficient to prove $u=0$ in $E$ implies $\nabla u = 0$ a.e. in $E$. Then one uses the result that the gradient of a function in $ W^{1,1}$ vanishes a.e. on the level sets of the function.

Answer (score 0):

A possible proof goes like follows. First, note that it is sufficient to prove that if $u=0$ a.e. on a Borel subset $E$ of $\Omega$ then $\nabla u=0$ a.e. in $E$. Now, it is possible to show [EG, Theorem 4.4] that if $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ then $\nabla u=0$ a.e. on the zero-level set $\{u=0\}$. But this concludes the proof because if $u=0$ a.e. in $E$ then $E\subseteq \{u=0\}$.

[EG] Evans Lawrence C. and Ronald F. Gariepy. *Measure theory and fine properties of functions*. Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2015.